# Exclude files on external hard drive from Unity Dash and recently used files

Tags: unity, hard-drive, unity-dash

For example, in the Dash search or in recently used files, thumbnails of pictures may come up that are private.

**Is there a way to disable the tracking of files that are on external hard drives?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is:

Open System Settings > "Security & Privacy" > "Files & Applications" (tab). Add the directory (or the complete drive) to the list to exclude from search. In most cases, you will need to clear the history (completely) and possibly log out / in to take effect.

From then on the files will not appear in search, nor in recently used items.

[image]