# How to hide files from search

Tags: 14.04, hidden-files

Using Ubuntu 14.04, how can I hide files, even from the computer search? I know about adding the dot to the beginning of file names, but this does not prevent hidden files and folders from showing up in my computer search results.

Comment: What do you mean with ‘computer search’? The results displayed if you type something in the dash (the transparent window that opens if you click on the Ubuntu icon in the upper left)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exclude files on external hard drive from Unity Dash and recently used files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/551800/exclude-files-on-external-hard-drive-from-unity-dash-and-recently-used-files)

Comment: @RobinKrahl- Yes, I guess it's "The Dash".

Answer (score 2):

You can set which directories you don't want to appear in the dash search, just open your Privacy settings and select them there.

Comment: This worked, I hadn't realized that these settings could be changed. Thank you.